# SOCAT (only) reverse tunnel

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, netcat, socat, socks5-proxy

I have a situation where we are trying to get data from one network to another - specifically access to a private maven repo on a different network.

Network 1 contains a maven repo. And network is protected by a couple SSH hops where port forwarding is disabled on `sshd`.

- [Laptop], running a Docker Container with VPN into other network `laptop`

  - Docker Container `vpn`
- [Jumpbox] `jumpbox.vpn.network.org`
- [Server] `server.vpn.network.org`

We have successfully run vscode-server on **server** and connect via:

```bsh
socat tcp-listen:8080,fork EXEC:"ssh server.vpn.network.org nc localhost 8081"
```

This lets laptop hit `localhost:8080` and it tunnels traffic into our `server.vpn` which then goes into netcat and sends the traffic into vscode server

I figure it should be possible to do the opposite I'm just getting stuck.

The goal would be to run a `Socks5` proxy on laptop via something like

```
ssh -f -N -D 54321 localhost
```

And then make a socat call into `server.vpn.network.org` and then using the socks env vars I could run maven and have it proxy back through the connection etc.

The approach I took was trying this:

```
socat -v TCP:localhost:54321 EXEC:"ssh server.vpn.network.org nc -lkv localhost 54321"
```

It was "sort" of working but kept dropping connection.

I then tried a combo of `fork` and `reuseaddr` and they didn't seem to solve the issue.

My next approach was to consider unix sockets or something funky - but I'm wondering if somebody knows how to make this work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your setup and what you want achieve. If I do, you might replace the first example just with:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8081 server.vpn.network.org
```

and the solution for reverse is:

```
ssh -R 54321:localhost:54321 server.vpn.network.org
```